# Is there a smarter way to access nested attributes using a DTO in NestJS?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

Stripe sends a webhook that looks like this

```
{
    "created": 1326853478,
    "livemode": false,
    "id": "evt_00000000000000",
    "type": "checkout.session.completed",
    "object": "event",
    "request": null,
    "pending_webhooks": 1,
    "api_version": "2016-07-06",
    "data": {
        "object": {
            "id": "cs_00000000000000",
            "object": "checkout.session",
            "billing_address_collection": null,
            "cancel_url": "https://example.com/cancel",
            "client_reference_id": "ABC",
            "customer": "DEF",
            "customer_email": null,
            "display_items": [
                {
                    "amount": 1500,
                    "currency": "usd",
                    "custom": {
                        "description": "Comfortable cotton t-shirt",
                        "images": null,
                        "name": "T-shirt"
                    },
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "type": "custom"
                }
            ],
            "livemode": false,
            "locale": null,
            "payment_intent": "pi_00000000000000",
            "payment_method_types": [
                "card"
            ],
            "submit_type": null,
            "subscription": null,
            "success_url": "https://example.com/success"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my controller that receives it:

```
import { Controller, Post, Body, ValidationPipe, UsePipes } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CheckoutWebhookDto } from './checkout-webhook.dto';

@Controller('webhooks')
export class StripeWebhooksController {

  @Post('checkout')
  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({transform: true}))
  async checkout(@Body() data: CheckoutWebhookDto) {
    console.log("Output:", data)
    return

  }

}
```

and my current Dto

```
import { ValidateNested, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';


export class CheckoutWebhookObjectDto  {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  readonly client_reference_id: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  readonly customer: string;
}

export class CheckoutWebhookDataDto  {
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => CheckoutWebhookObjectDto)
  readonly object: CheckoutWebhookObjectDto;
}

export class CheckoutWebhookDto  {
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => CheckoutWebhookDataDto)
  readonly data: CheckoutWebhookDataDto;
}
```

I want to extract out

`data.object.client_reference_id` and `data.object.customer`

The only way I can do this is to create 3 Dtos nested inside each other.

I appreciate I can do `@Body('data')` to shorten it to 2 - but is there a way to have a single Dto so that the final data object is just:

```
{
  client_reference_id: "ABC",
  customer: "DEF"
}
```

Comment: I think your best bet would be to use a pipe, but even then you'll still have to use the three DTOs to be able to whittle away at the unwanted fields. Seeing as you are using `class-transformer, you could create a method that allows you to get such fields you're looking for. I'm not aware of better solutions at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @JayMcDoniel. Eventually found [@types/stripe-v3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/stripe-v3) which helps validate the event - but couldn't find a way to solve the original problem.